# Hive - Exception when selecting a table

Tags: hive

```
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /tmp/hive-root/hive_2013-08-15_13-28-46_129_8286357465917641024/-mr-10002/1/emptyFile could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1639)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:729)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:578)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1393)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1389)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1387)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:229)
    at $Proxy5.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:85)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:62)
    at $Proxy5.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.locateFollowingBlock(DFSClient.java:3686)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSClient.java:3546)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.access$2600(DFSClient.java:2749)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSClient.java:2989)
Job Submission failed with exception 'org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException: File /tmp/hive-root/hive_2013-08-15_13-28-46_129_8286357465917641024/-mr-10002/1/emptyFile could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1639)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:729)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:578)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1393)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1389)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1387)
```

Comment: This question tells us nothing.  Please give us some code, explain what you're trying to do and tell us what your problem is

Answer (score 0):

"could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1" usually means insufficient space on datanode. Or maybe datanode is down at all.